# Conditional mysql join?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one table is for users, and the other table is user_interested_in_who table.

The idea is if a user is interested in another user, I will insert the ids for those two users to the user_interested_in_who table

The schema for my tables are:

```
Users               user_interested_in_who
  id                id
  name              this_user (id from the users table)
                    interested_in_this_user (id from the users table)
                    interested_or_not (1 = yes, 0 = no)
```

So I want to query my tables by joining them together, my query is like this:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, user_interested_in_who.interested_or_not
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_interested_in_who
ON user_interested_in_who.this_user = 1 *//1 is the id of the current log in user*
GROUP BY users.id
```

The problem with this query is that the interested_or_not column all have 1. Even when the interested_or_not column have 0 in the record

My question is how can I query it to return NULL if no record is found on the user_interested_in_who table and how can I query it to return 0 in the user_interested_or_not column if the record is 0

---

Edit:

How can I make it return this kind of table:

```
table:
id | name | interested_or_not
1    jess   NULL
2    erika  1
3    jil    0
4    adrian NULL
....
1050 mich   1
```

Comment: I think the answer from @Alan is close to what you want.  However, the structure of our Who's interested in Who should be simplified to Peron1 and Person2.  Why create a record for pairs of people 1:2, 1:3, 1:4 and again for the reverse.. 2:1, 3:1, 4:1. you will get bloated data allowing both combinations of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN but with no literal value in your ON clause.

This will return all the entries in the first table and either their match in the second table or NULL.

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, user_interested_in_who.interested_or_not
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_interested_in_who 
   ON user_interested_in_who.this_user = users.id
```

There is no need to GROUP, and you don't need a WHERE for your example case (which you have showing all the values?).  If you do want to limit to a User ID then modify as follows:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, user_interested_in_who.interested_or_not
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_interested_in_who 
   ON user_interested_in_who.this_user = users.id 
WHERE users.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`. `JOIN` will return only the records in both tables  You also need a where clause instead of using the user's logged in id to create the join.

You dont need to group anything, that's why you're always getting 1.

This should do what you want.

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, user_interested_in_who.interested_or_not
FROM users
JOIN user_interested_in_who
ON user_interested_in_who.this_user = users.id
WHERE users.id=1;
```

Comment: hello, thank you for helping me out. but there's a problem in this query because i'm querying all the users in the user table. If i use this query, then it will just return single row.

Comment: @KevinLee: So just remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: really join? i thought left join